# How to enable/ disable the button if the time reaches the desired time?

Tags: vb.net, button, datetimepicker

I have 2 date time picker(dtpDate & dtpTime) that show the current date and time. I also have a button labeled time-out, what I want to do is if the dtpTime reaches 12:00 noon I want the time-out button to be enable. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Show what you've tried and where you think you're having the issue.

Comment: @AtanHokage04 You need double quotes here

Comment: I try this code: if dtpTime.value='12:00:00' then btnTime-out.enable=false

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle Events because the dateTimePicker's value may change.

In the following code, I handle `dtpTime.ValueChanged` and `MyBase.Load`

```
Private Sub dtpTime_ValueChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles dtpTime.ValueChanged, MyBase.Load
    If dtpTime.Text = "12:00:00" Then
        ' Enable your button
        btnTimeOut.Enabled = True
        'MsgBox("Hello")
    End If
End Sub
```